# Event to listen for when spawning babel with --watch flag

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, watch

I'm trying to create a script to babel compile one directory, output to another directory and then run a second function when compilation is complete.

I need to run babel in watch mode.

Ideally the code will look like this:

```
const babel = spawn("babel", [
  "sourceDir",
  "--watch",
  "--out-dir",
  "outputDir"
])

babel.on('compile', () => {
  runSecondaryScript();
})
```

Because the directory will have multiple files in it and the number of files will change as I continue to develop, I can't trigger the second script from the `stdout` because it outputs for every individual file it runs through.

e.g.

```
sourceDir/file1.js -> outputDir/file1.js
sourceDir/file2.js -> outputDir/file2.js
```

Comment: Have you considered watching for filesystem events in the output directory, and calling your second script at that time?

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up doing. I use fs to do a file count, and then count the stdouts of Babel. When the 2 numbers match I run the second script.